# Flutter Web How to Convert Uint8List to File

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-web, uint8list

I am having trouble on converting Uint8List image to File on flutter web since dart:io is not supported on the web, i need it to be file in order to upload it to FirebaseStorage, is there any workaround for this ? thankyou

Answer (score 8):

Since `dart:io` isn't avalible on web, you can use the `universal_io` package.

Add it to your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';

File createFileFromBytes(Uint8List bytes) => File.fromRawPath(bytes);
```

Comment: isnt dart : io not supported on flutter-web?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `dart:io` isn't avalibe on web, but you can use the `universal_io` package.

Comment: ah thankyou i dont know that package exist, will accept your answer after i tried it

Comment: Okay, here is the package on pub: https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io

Comment: For me, this returns `Error: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0)`. There are several similar issues reported and the author has yet to reply to any of them.

Comment: This is not the answer, this uses the Uint8List as the file path, not the actual contents

Comment: Error: FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 402)

Any solution?